How to stop Visual Studio Code auto indenting on new line
I use visual studio code for Typescript a lot because I work with Angular.
For some reason, I have noticed recently that whenever I type out an if statement (for example) it auto indents when I enter the next line.
For example:
if (isSuccessful)
  {
    //braces are in the wrong place because of auto indent
  }

How do I stop this?
Thanks
